# GWT-RPC deserialization: About the way minus works

Tags: java, gwt, deserialization, token, rpc

### Questions about minus symbol interpretation while performing deserialization in environments where third-party libraries are unavailable.

Response data is as follows.

//OK[...,26,1,61,2,-37,59,20,-59,64,2,-35,'...',35,-33,63,2,-57,33,2,-31,100,6,-55,44312.08024040509,31,-29,62,2,-53,29,2,-27,25,2,-23,'XkK1PiA',23,-21,55,2,-51,44311.875,31,-49,'XkK1PiA',23,-47,61,2,-45,60,20,-43,59,20,-19,18,2,-17,58,2,-15,57,2,-13,12,2,-11,56,2,-39,55,2,-9,24,1,...,["java.util.HashMap","java.lang.String",...],0,7]

I checked the count of java.util.HashMap. What does the index with the **minus** sign mean after that?

Have a nice day.

Comment: Verified that it is an index of its own command stack.

Comment: A given value in the payload section of the response (one of the numbers not in the string table) can mean different things depending on where in the object graph you are in your deserialization - it could mean a literal negative number, it could mean an already-seen object reference (i.e. "dont deserialize this again, you already saw it"). Can you provide more details about what you do know so far?